# Как в БД записать сложный объект C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2

Значит у меня есть база данных следующей схемы :

```
namespace eShop.Entities
{
public class ListCities
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CityArea> CityAreas { get; set; } = new List<CityArea>();
}

public class CityArea
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; } = new List<City>();
}

public class City
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AppUser> AppUsers = new List<AppUser>();
}
```

}

Ко мне с фронта приходит объект в json формате, который я конвертирую в объект ListCities. Вот пример

```
[HttpPost]
    public async void Post(string jsonData)
    {
        ListCities list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListCities>(jsonData);
        await _cityRepository.SaveCitiesAsync(list);
    }
```

Как мне правильно реализовать метод SaveCitiesAsync() чтобы данный объект сразу заносился в базу данных с учетом всех связей и разносился по нужным таблицам?

```
public async Task SaveCitiesAsync(ListCities listCities)
    {
        ListCities newListCities = new ListCities {
           //как писать код тут?
        };
        await Context.ListCities.AddAsync(newListCities);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: *как писать код тут?* — вообще удалите это и пишите `Context.ListCities.AddAsync(listCities);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context.ListCities.AddAsync(listCities); – решение. Спасибо.