# Как JSON записать в MS SQL с помощью EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

У меня есть данные в формате JSON по этой с этого источника: https://api.hh.ru/areas/5.
Как создать для этого объекта модель и как его записать в базу данных с помощью EF core??
Помогите.

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Вы не знаете как десериализовать JSON или не знаете как писать данные в БД?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947307/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-c вот вопрос который я задавал до этого, ответа я не получил. Решил зайти с более абстрактной стороны.